# mysqldump to backup database from linux to windows server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql server on a linux box (192.168.1.20) which has database named "retail". I want to create an automatic way to do a backup on windows server (192.168.1.30).

What is the best way to run the following code to do so :

```
mysqldump -h 192.168.1.20 -u root -p Retail > C:\Retail_Initiative\backup_20110315.sql
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about making a windows scheduled task that runs the above command? Seems straight forward for the use case?

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite your question, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Just thinking about the upvote which originally means 'This question is useful and clear'... :)

Comment: Why not have the Linux box run the backup dump and then just grab the SQL file from a shared Samba share?

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a bat file with:

```
/START /WAIT mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -h192.168.1.20 retail > path_to_dump_file
/START /WAIT mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -h192.168.1.30 -e "DROP DATABASE retail; CREATE DATABASE retail;"
/START /WAIT mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -h192.168.1.30 retail < path_to_dump_file
```

That should do it.